Advice for painting gas wall heater
I have this old gas wall heater that is a real eyesore. Is it safe to spray paint it in place with a high heat spray paint if I cover the igniter & fan mechanisms at the top and bottom(see pics)? The center grille isn't removable unless I uninstall the whole thing.



Spray painting is not friendly in a house, without a lot of protection of the walls/ceiling/floor/anything else.  A small can and a couple of dollar store brushes will do the job.

Are you sure that entire louvered box can't be removed for painting?  It looks like the "guts" of the heater are embedded in the wall.

Paint the walls tan to match the heater?
